# asp.net 5 kestrel : sometime, unable to bind socket on a free port

Tags: sockets, asp.net-core, bind, kestrel

While trying to start an asp.net 5 kestrel website, I sometime got this error :
Failed to bind to address http://localhost:5000
"An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions."

The only way to solve the issue is to reboot the computer.
The port (5000) is not in use in TCPView or NETSTAT.
I tried to explicitly allow the app in the windows firewall, but no luck either. Same with fully deactivating the firewall.
I got this issue with a published website (kestrel) without any visual studio, and also in debug from VS2019.

My customers also have the issue around 1 day in a month, without any apparent reason.

Do you have any idea to help me track down this issue ?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you google this? There are tons of articles on how to fix this. Start here: https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2014/10/wininit-exe-stealing-port-5000/ Move it to port 5001 and you won't have the conflict anymore.

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks for pointing this.

I don't have the registry key under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Rpc\Internet.

so I assume RDP is using either < 4999 port or the whole netsh ephemeral range (which on my win10 computer include the whole 1024-65554 range so it's unlikely to lock a port indefinitely).

On mcbsys post, the issue was that the registry key explicitly point to 5000. That's not the case on my computer. Again thanks for pointing me this article, I learned something today.